# Twisted pair with shield and drain wire

Tags: impedance, cables, shielding, characteristic-impedance, twisted-pair

Ive been posed with a problem regarding calculating the characteristic impedance of a shielded twisted pair with a drain wire. While I understand how to calculate this for a "normal" shielded twisted pair, Im struggling to understand how (if at all) the drain wire would affect the answer.

Background:

The application is a particle detector, in which space for cabling is at an absolute premium. People are losing hair over trying to find spare millimeters to route the cables for the elements in their areas. There is also a lot of repitition of cables, so shaving a mm off one *type* of cable for instance, adds up to a not insignificant saving over the whole detector.

In the section I work in, we are connecting hundreds of internal chips to the outside world over a CAN bus each. Grounding and shielding requirements dictate that CANH and CANL for the CAN line are contained within a foil shielded twisted pair. Management have however requested that we insert a drain wire into this twisted pair as a current return path (please see a basic image below), as it saves on the insulation mass of routing it as a single wire. We have found a company willing to produce this cable for us, but before we purchase any samples (which i could perform time domain reflectometry on), ive been asked to calculate the characteristic impedance of it. For information, the CAN speed is 125kbps, so it is my understanding that we dont treat it as a transmission line.

[image: Shielded twisted pair. Conductors in red, insulation orange and yellow, and shield in grey](conductors in red, foil shield in grey, and insulation in orange and yellow)

[image: The equivelant cross section if a seperate wire is used]
(The equivelant cross section if a seperate wire is used)

From the following [reference page of cable design equations](http://www.standard-wire.com/cable_design_equations.html), I can see that even a jacket on the outside of the shield (as I have) affects the impedance equation, but I have been unable to find any reference explaining mathematically how a drain wire would affect the equation. Anecdotaly I would imagine that the impedance of the shielding will be reduced due to a larger cross sectional area, but cant say much more than that. From my googling, I havent come across any instances of someone trying the same thing, and personally ive only ever used shielded twisted pairs *without* a drain wire. It may be that theres a good reason for this, in which case im happy to go back to management and tell them so, but im stumped. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Edit: Have added a sketch showing a rough idea of how this saves space compared to having the return line in a seperate wire.

Comment: *"Management have however requested that we insert a drain wire into this twisted pair as a current return path"* - this begs the question as to whether "management" are qualified to make this call and, if qualified, for what purpose is the drain wire (other than making an easy connection to the shield)?

Comment: Arguably, theyre not! And thats why I am more than prepared to go back and tell them no if theres a good reason, but I need to be able to justify it.

Comment: The drain wire will be the ground connection to the asic that the CAN bus connects to.

Comment: So ask them why they want it and get them to justify the cost for bespoke cable.

Comment: They want it as it saves space elsewhere for other cables.

Comment: Adding a drain wire bulks out a cable (as you have drawn it).

Comment: Perhaps my language has caused the confusion. When i say "adding a drain wire to the twisted pair", it means one less wire outside the twisted pair, and as an external wire would also have the overhead of its own insulation, this way saves on space.

Comment: The main reason I've seen drain wires used is that they make termination easier (e.g. in large audio installations). Anyway it shouldn't need bespoke cable - twin screened with a drain is widely available, and should work fine at this bit rate. Also - is the Zo of the cable that critical at these bit rates? it all seems a bit confused to me.

Comment: The easier termination is definitely an advantage to us. The reason for being bespoke is due to it being in an irradiated environment thus requiring non standard insulation materials.

Comment: The closer ground wire has a higher capacitance to each of the signal wires, providing a lower impedance path between them, and reducing the characteristic impedance.  Probably not to the extent that it makes the bus unusable, but a potential change.

Comment: OK, if you need special insulation I guess bespoke cable might be needed. But if you are *not* treating it as a a transmission line, why are you worrying about small effects on Zo?

Comment: What is the longest distance from the sensor/CAN transmitter to the CAN receiver? And as particle detectors may need time-sensitive data response, does the CAN data links provide that?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf No more than a few metres, although the exact distance is not yet finalised. The CAN lines carry non-time critical data. The high speed stuff is out of my remit.

Comment: @dmb Weve got to prove beyond reasonable doubt that weve covered everything in design review before we can purchase. Normally, we could order prototypes and samples, but because this is bespoke, the minimum order quantity is out of prototyping budget. Theyve asked for the characteristic impedance for system simulation. It may be that I need to press them on how its going to help their simulations...

Comment: can you find an off the shelf cable whose dielectric has similar properties? it sounds like design by committee for something which should not ever be a problem. Yes I would ask them why they are worrying about Zo is cable lengths and frequencies are such that transmission line effects are not significant.

Comment: good lord, if you are doing less than 1Mbit data rate and only a few metres this really is a silly exercise. No doubt it is costing someone's taxes ...

Comment: @dmb Fair enough, I will go back to them and press them on why they need this, given the data rate and cable length. Its not my area of expertise and as I say, even after research I wasnt really sure if this drain wire was going to have any effects that we needed to think about. Thanks for the advice!